# different cardinalities for relationship in NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: core-data, subclass, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

Is it possible to set different maximum number of objects in a two many relationship in core data? I was thinking it might be possible with the `NSRelationshipDescription -setMaxCount:` method, but I can't figure out where to call this. Would I call it in a custom `+initialization` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a setting to set the maximum number of objects. Use the core data inspector to set your property on your relationship.

[image]

Comment: How can you use that if the relationship is defined in the superclass?

Comment: you on on the definition of the relationship. In this case, the superclass. Inheritance will work.

Comment: My question though is is it possible for different subclasses to have different maximums?

Comment: you can subclass the core data generated accessors to handle your own logic, and use the superclass for the minimum acceptable maximum